# Count the number of lattice with same number of neighbouring lattice

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have a set of coordinate of the lattice in a file named "Lattice.txt". My code below  check the number of neighbour for each of the lattice-

```
void CheckLattice(int b)
{
   vector<Lattice> lattices;

   /* reading from file logic */
   ifstream theFile("Lattice.txt");
   double x1,y1,x2,y2;
   while (theFile >> x1 >> y1 >> x2 >> y2) {
      lattices.push_back(Lattice(x1,y1, x2,y2));
   }

   /* counting neighbors logic */
   int lattice_count = 0;
   int GroupLattice=0;
   for (int x = 0; x < lattices.size(); ++x) {
      if (lattices[b].NearestLattice(lattices[x])) {
         if (x==b) {
            continue; //this is our lattice , skip it.
         }
         lattice_count++;
      }
      GroupLattice++;
   }

   cout<<"Lattice "<<(b+1)<<" has = "<<lattice_count<<" neighbours "<<endl;
   cout << " The number of lattice with "<< lattice_count << " neighbours are " << GroupLattice << endl;
   cout << endl;

}

int main()
{
   int neighbour=0; 
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
      CheckLattice(i);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

It returns the value like this-

> ```
> Lattice 1 has = 7 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 7 neighbours are 14
>
> Lattice 2 has = 3 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 3 neighbours are 15
>
> Lattice 3 has = 8 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 8 neighbours are 14
>
> Lattice 4 has = 6 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 6 neighbours are 15
>
> Lattice 5 has = 8 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 8 neighbours are 14
>
> Lattice 6 has = 8 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 8 neighbours are 15
>
> Lattice 7 has = 8 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 8 neighbours are 14
>
> Lattice 8 has = 1 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 1 neighbours are 15
>
> Lattice 9 has = 7 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 7 neighbours are 14
>
> Lattice 10 has = 5 neighbours 
>  The number of lattice with 5 neighbours are 15
> ```

Though this code returns the *number of neighbour for each of the lattice correctly*, **it does not** returns the value of the total number of lattice with same quantity of neighbour. **Instead it's only return 14 or 15! How can I fix that?**

I want the output something like this-

> ```
> Lattice 1 has = 7 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 2 has = 3 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 3 has = 8 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 4 has = 6 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 5 has = 8 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 6 has = 8 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 7 has = 8 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 8 has = 1 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 9 has = 7 neighbours 
>
> Lattice 10 has = 5 neighbours 
>
>  The number of lattice with 1 neighbours are 1
>  The number of lattice with 2 neighbours are 1
>  The number of lattice with 7 neighbours are 2
>  The number of lattice with 8 neighbours are 4 ...etc
> ```

I might have missed something. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: I think he means lattice points in a solid crystal.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik : You are right. I mean the [lattice points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_structure)

Comment: why are you reading the file 10 times?

Comment: @BenVoigt: It doesn't have to be only 10 times. I want to run it for 100 lattices. I have just pasted a sample result for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't print the number of lattices with the same number of neighbors is because you have no logic at all to see whether `lattices[x]` has the same number of neighbors as `lattices[b]`, you just could every lattice that doesn't hit the `continue`.

In fact, you haven't stored the number of neighbors which `lattice[x]` has.

I suggest that you reorganize your code to

- read the data from file *once* into a data structure that lasts throughout the program
- count the number of neighbors each lattice has, and *store that value with the lattice* as well as printing it
- use the stored numbers of neighbors to finish your task

Comment: I was already thinking  of storing the value of the number of neighbour for the lattice. But could not figure out how. I have tried using the arrays but no luck. May be I have done something wrong. Could you please help me out with a sample code?